# Partial Match in Full Text search in SQL Server 2014 failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index, full-text-catalog

I have implemented full text search in SQL Server 2014. I need partial match implementation in full text search in SQL Server 2014.

When I type **'erik grant'**, the results are given below

[image]

When I type **'ran'**, I am expecting all the names containing **'ran'** as partial match. Especially all the names with last name **'grant'** should be returned in the query result. But the result is empty. Partial match is not working. I am expecting **LIKE '%ran%'** behaviour.

[image]

Need your suggestions and guidance in partial match implementation in **FULLTEXT SEARCH**.

Thanks

Comment: That's the way SQL Server fulltext search works - it's a **word-based** searching - it's not a `LIKE '%....%'` across the whole database ...

Comment: I know, this leading wildcard does not use any Index. @marc_s, Is there any way to achieve the desired results?

Comment: I don't know of any *easy* way to do this. I have wanted to look into Lucene / Elasticsearch for a while, but haven't gotten around to that just yet - but if you have the time and opportunity, those are two technologies I'd check out and see if they offer what you're looking for